# How to resolve SqlConnection error "Keyword not supported: 'decr pool size'."

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I am creating Windows Application and using System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection object

```
 SqlConnection targetDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
```

Following is the connection string

```
Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TestBCP_12;User ID=sa;Password=sa;Min Pool Size=100; Max Pool Size=100; Decr Pool Size=100; Incr Pool Size=100;
```

Getting error with the following two settings

```
 Decr Pool Size=100; Incr Pool Size=100;
```

I know all the sizes are 100 , is it the cause of exception if yes? , the message is not reverent to the error .

I read the following article and implemented based on it
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17768/ADO-NET-Connection-Pooling-at-a-Glance

Found the answer that this is not possible in SQL directly so asked new question 
[How to achieve functionlity i.e. controlling "Incr Pool Size" or "Decr Pool Size" while establishing connection to SQL? similar to ORACLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429562/how-to-achieve-functionlity-i-e-controlling-incr-pool-size-or-decr-pool-size)
to find other possible ways to achieve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using SqlConnection, it does not support `Decr Pool Size` or `Incr Pool Size`. This property is supported with [OracleConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

You may check this article: [Connection Pooling in DotNet](http://www.programmersheaven.com/user/sreeharikv/blog/295-Connection-Pooling-in-DotNet/)

From the article:

> You should refer to the documentation if you're using a .NET Data
>   Provider other than SQL Server. Other data providers may have more
>   pooling options. A good example is the Oracle Data Provider, which
>   offers two options -- Decr Pool Size and Incr Pool Size -- for
>   controlling how a connection pool may shrink or grow.

Comment: i read http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17768/ADO-NET-Connection-Pooling-at-a-Glance before using it , it does not say about oracle

Comment: @ImranRizvi, at a glance, it looks like the author is talking about both Oracle as well as SQL connection, but forgot to mention that Decr Pool Size and Incr Pool Size can't be used with SQLConnection

Comment: I believe you. is there any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: @ImranRizvi, you may specify Min Pool Size and Max Pool Size, I am not sure if you can Increase or decrease the pool size, You may ask a new question regarding this.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I've created new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429562/how-to-achieve-functionlity-i-e-controlling-incr-pool-size-or-decr-pool-size

Answer (score 1):

The list of accepted keywords is [documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx). Neither `Decr Pool Size` nor `Incr Pool Size` are listed there.

Comment: I believe you. is there any other way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

You Are using a syntax for [Oracle connection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/featConnecting.htm) strings against a SqlServer database.

`DECR POOL SIZE` and `INCR POOL SIZE` are not supported in SqlServer connections.

Simply remove these two parts from your connection.
Also I suggest to remove the `Max Pool Size=100;` since this is the default value.
The `Min Pool Size=100;` could also be removed if there is no special requirement to have an initial minimum size

Comment: is there any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: Can only point to this article where the mechanics of connection pooling is explained in fine details [Sql Server - Understanding and controlling connection pooling fragmentation](http://www.pythian.com/news/1270/sql-server-understanding-and-controlling-connection-pooling-fragmentation/)