# How to achieve functionlity i.e. controlling "Incr Pool Size" or "Decr Pool Size" while establishing connection to SQL? similar to ORACLE

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have asked a question about "Incr Pool Size" or "Decr Pool Size"

[How to resolve SqlConnection error "Keyword not supported: 'decr pool size'."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427362/how-to-resolve-sqlconnection-error-keyword-not-supported-decr-pool-size/11427442#comment15077277_11427442)

This is another but different question related to that , in brief ORACLE connection string provides these two option to increase/decrease connection objects when connection pool is empty or full respectively. how can we achieve this with SQL.

EDIT: Why I want to know because I am creating a middleware where I am writing to database using multiple parallel threads (e.g. 60), what I am thinking is when all my connections from pool (e.g. 50) are in use and new bunch of threads try to create connection will sql server will create another bunch of connection in pool i.e. 50 or will it create this exceeding connection one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SqlClient manages the pool size automatically, whithin the [`MaxPoolSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.maxpoolsize) and [`MinPoolSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.minpoolsize) parameters provided. The default values are 100 and 0, respectively.

Comment: how does it manage it? suppose if all connections are occupied how many new connections will be created?

Comment: You should simply set the `MaxPoolSize` to a value large enough. You middleware should throttle requests (IIS would already do this for you if you're code is hosted as a web service or running in ASP.Net). How each client driver handles an outburst of new connections requests differs from driver to driver. The SqlClient driver offers no control.

Comment: will writing custom class for connection pool with incr decr size would help?

Comment: No. Do you have an actual use case when you're running out of connecitons and the pool does not increase its size? Are you trying to solve a *real* problem or are you just speculating?

Comment: No, I am not getting any problem, my only concern is to get best from connection pooling or save time difference between creating one connection and bunch of connections